# ia32 calling convention registers clobbered?

Tags: c, x86, stack, cpu-registers

I have the following two files, the first one creates a signal handler for SIGUSR1, which sets up a fake call to the function foo() in the interrupted context. The second file is a template header for accessing IA32 registers.

stack.c:

```
#ifdef HARMONY
#define LINUX
#include "hythread.h"
#endif

#ifndef _GNU_SOURCE
#define _GNU_SOURCE             // so that string.h will include strsignal()
#endif
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdarg.h>             // va_list, va_start(), va_end()
#ifndef __USE_GNU         // Deal with current ucontext ugliness.  The current
#define __USE_GNU         // mess of asm/ucontext.h & sys/ucontext.h and their
#include <sys/ucontext.h> // mutual exclusion on more recent versions of gcc
#undef __USE_GNU          // dictates this ugly hack.
#else
#include <sys/ucontext.h>
#endif
#include <assert.h>

#include "linux_ucontext.h"

#define DBG(fncn,name) if (fncn) { perror(name); return 1; }

void foo(void *fp) {
  printf("Inside foo(%p)\n", fp);
}

typedef long unsigned int* Address;

void handler(int signo, siginfo_t *si, void *context) {
  if (signo == SIGUSR1) {
    printf("Handling SIGUSR1...\n");

    // Set fake pointer (0xDEADBEEF) as first argument to foo()
    Address sp = (Address)IA32_ESP(context);
    IA32_ESP(context) = IA32_ESP(context) - sizeof(void *);
    sp = (Address)IA32_ESP(context);
    ((Address *)sp)[0]  = IA32_EIP(context);
    IA32_EAX(context) = 0xDEADBEEF;

    // Put return address of interrupted instruction onto stack
    IA32_ESP(context) = IA32_ESP(context) - sizeof(void *);
    sp = IA32_ESP(context);
    ((Address *)sp)[0] = IA32_EIP(context);

    // Setup function call to foo()
    IA32_EIP(context) = foo;

    return;
  }
  printf("Received unknown signal signo=%d\n",signo);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  struct sigaction action;
  memset(&action, 0, sizeof(action));
  action.sa_sigaction = &handler;

  // Mask all signals from reaching handler while handler is running
  DBG(sigfillset(&(action.sa_mask)),"sigfillset");

  DBG(sigdelset(&(action.sa_mask), SIGCONT),"sigdelset");
  action.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO | SA_ONSTACK | SA_RESTART;

  action.sa_sigaction = &handler;
  DBG(sigaction(SIGUSR1, &action, 0),"sigaction")

  int count = 0;
  while (1) {
    sleep(1);
    printf("Inside while loop %08d...\n",count);
    count += 1;
  }

}
```

linux_context.h:

```
/*
 *  This file is part of the Jikes RVM project (http://jikesrvm.org).
 *
 *  This file is licensed to You under the Eclipse Public License (EPL);
 *  You may not use this file except in compliance with the License. You
 *  may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.opensource.org/licenses/eclipse-1.0.php
 *
 *  See the COPYRIGHT.txt file distributed with this work for information
 *  regarding copyright ownership.
 */
#ifndef JRVM_LINUX_IA32_UCONTEXT
#define JRVM_LINUX_IA32_UCONTEXT

#define __MC(context) ((ucontext_t*)context)->uc_mcontext
#define __GREGS(context) (__MC(context).gregs)

#ifndef __x86_64__
#  define IA32_EAX(context) (__GREGS(context)[REG_EAX])
#  define IA32_EBX(context) (__GREGS(context)[REG_EBX])
#  define IA32_ECX(context) (__GREGS(context)[REG_ECX])
#  define IA32_EDX(context) (__GREGS(context)[REG_EDX])
#  define IA32_EDI(context)  (__GREGS(context)[REG_EDI])
#  define IA32_ESI(context)  (__GREGS(context)[REG_ESI])
#  define IA32_EBP(context)  (__GREGS(context)[REG_EBP])
#  define IA32_ESP(context) (__GREGS(context)[REG_ESP])
#  define IA32_EIP(context)  (__GREGS(context)[REG_EIP])

#  define IA32_CS(context)  (__GREGS(context)[REG_CS])
#  define IA32_DS(context)  (__GREGS(context)[REG_DS])
#  define IA32_ES(context)  (__GREGS(context)[REG_ES])
#  define IA32_FS(context)  (__GREGS(context)[REG_FS])
#  define IA32_GS(context)  (__GREGS(context)[REG_GS])
#  define IA32_SS(context)  (__GREGS(context)[REG_SS])

#  define IA32_OLDMASK(context) (__MC(context).oldmask)
#  define IA32_FPFAULTDATA(context)     (__MC(context).cr2)
#else
#  define IA32_EAX(context) (__GREGS(context)[REG_RAX])
#  define IA32_EBX(context) (__GREGS(context)[REG_RBX])
#  define IA32_ECX(context) (__GREGS(context)[REG_RCX])
#  define IA32_EDX(context) (__GREGS(context)[REG_RDX])
#  define IA32_EDI(context)  (__GREGS(context)[REG_RDI])
#  define IA32_ESI(context)  (__GREGS(context)[REG_RSI])
#  define IA32_EBP(context)  (__GREGS(context)[REG_RBP])
#  define IA32_ESP(context) (__GREGS(context)[REG_RSP])
#  define IA32_EIP(context)  (__GREGS(context)[REG_RIP])
#endif

#define IA32_EFLAGS(context)  (__GREGS(context)[REG_EFL])
#define IA32_TRAPNO(context) (__GREGS(context)[REG_TRAPNO])
#define IA32_ERR(context) (__GREGS(context)[REG_ERR])
#define IA32_FALUTVADDR(context) (__GREGS(context)[REG_CS])

#define IA32_FPREGS(context) (__MC(context).fpregs)

// reg = 0..7, n = 0 .. 3
#define IA32_STMM(context, reg, n) (IA32_FPREGS(context)->_st[reg].significand[n])
#define IA32_STMMEXP(context, reg) (IA32_FPREGS(context)->_st[reg].exponent)

/* Currently unused
#define IA32_XMM(context, reg, n) \
*/

#endif
```

When I compile and run this, and hit the process with a SIGUSR1, foo() is called correctly and returns back to the while loop. However when I set up a similar signal handler which interrupts some arbitrary code (running a JVM), the fake "foo()" executes correctly but the  process segmentation faults when it returns to the arbitrary interrupted code.

Am I clobbering some registers in the fake function call? Also what am I doing wrong in trying to pass 0xDEADBEEF to foo (right now it seems to be printing a garbage pointer)?

Comment: Umm, your `foo` doesn't bother to restore every register when it returns, right? So the JVM is going to execute some code, and from its perspective some registers randomly change value during execution...very bad results will be had.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Why not just call `foo` from your handler directly?

Comment: Actually, reading your code a bit further, it seems you are also clobbering the stack. This could break if the interrupted code was in the middle of setting up a function call, for example. The whole thing is just terribly fragile. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: I didn't call `foo` directly from the handler because the `foo` in the JVM is compiled from java, and this is how the JVM handles jumping into compiled java code when it receives other software and hardware signals.

Now that you mention it though I'll try calling it directly from the handler...